# Problems with drake build and "from pydrake.all import"

Tags: drake

I'm having problems with using `from pydrake.all import (MathematicalProgram, Polynomial)` after building drake from source (reference https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html). Per the previous link, installation steps were:

```
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake ../drake -DWITH_MOSEK=ON
make -j
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

After installing and running `from pydrake.all import (MathematicalProgram, Polynomial)` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "$HOME/drake-build/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/all.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .perception import *
ImportError: ImportError: $HOME/drake-build/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/systems/framework.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5drake7systems6SystemIdE19DoCheckValidContextERKNS0_11ContextBaseE
```

I don't get this error if I use the nightly build binaries (instead of building from source), but I'm having separate problems with the nightly build binaries and want to rely on building from git.

Using Ubuntu 18.04, Python3.6.

Comment: Can you try running your test command (`python3 -c 'import pydrake.all`) in an isolated environment? (I've made [an example in this gist](https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/dd5bc43eeb05d1fb50277f236872d98b))  Also, can you print out the compiler being used? See the [Getting Help - Helpful Information](https://drake.mit.edu/getting_help.html#helpful-information) docs.

Comment: As an update, I was able to run the example script on my machine without a hitch. (I've updated it to be use a fixed git checkout as well.)

Comment: Currently working on it.  I'm not able to run the script completely for VPN issues: I simultaneously need internet+VPN to git clone, or must disable VPN+internet to make (Bazel is unable to connect to a local Bazel server at the start of the build if VPN is connected).

Comment: Importing pydrake.all is working now. Like I said, I couldn't run your script for VPN issues, but I think the trick was building from the commit you provided? My previous drake build was from 4bd63e3ee53252414b6b0aab15cc6a1711748839.

What I did:
`cp drake drake_git_test -r`
`git clean -fd #Remove some local __pycache__ files and a jdk install file`
`git checkout cacac0aa1`
`mkdir drake-build-test`
`cd drake-build-test`
`cmake ../drake_git_test/ -DWITH_MOSEK=ON`
`make`
`export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/drake-build-test/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages"`
`python3 -c 'import pydrake.all'`

Comment: Notably, I didn't run any of the env commands from your script, the only real difference was the build commit.

Comment: Huh... interesting that the commit was the thing that fixed it (I don't see a huge difference along the lines of 4bd63e3..cacac0aa1), and sorry that you have to deal with the wonky VPN+disconnect setup -- but glad it works!

Comment: That being said, would you be up for writing a self-answer here? (maybe just to state that it's fixed, and link to your above steps?)
(TBH, it still seems like there may have been something like a stale artifact accidentally leftover that might have been fixed by `git clean -fd` - I'm not sure if you want to dig into that further and do root-cause analysis, as it may be hard to reproduce. Let me know!)

Comment: @EricCousineau, done, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Sweet, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the build directory and repeating the steps given in https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#building-the-python-bindings:

```
rm -rf drake-build
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake ../drake -DWITH_MOSEK=ON
make -j
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

A previous build must have gone wonky and the vestiges were preventing a correct build afterwards.  I'm not sure on the root cause of the first "bad build," but it doesn't seem to be related to the commit I was previously on (4bd63e3ee) since the re-build from that commit is also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set your PYTHONPATH environment variable? You could do

```
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

as mentioned in https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#building-the-python-bindings

Comment: Yes I am already doing that (forgot to meant to include that in my steps).